# 2G or 3G data API

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to write an app to send data to a phone number using 2G or 3G Network? If so, what are the APIs that are available? Is there one for this purpose in J2ME. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use push registry technology.

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/